# LLVM OS X symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 compile error

Tags: macos, compilation, llvm, clang

I have succesfully compiled the `LLVM kalidoscope` examples in C.

Now I'm extending the code with:

```
#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"

static cl::opt<std::string> InputFilename(cl::Positional, cl::desc("<input file>"), cl::Required);

int mail(...
```

now i compile using:

clang++ -g toy.cpp `llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --libs all` -O3 -o toy

and after this change i receive the following error:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "typeinfo for llvm::cl::GenericOptionValue", referenced from:
      typeinfo for llvm::cl::OptionValueCopy<std::string> in toy-Pq1GSI.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

What could be wrong, and how can i fix it?

Versions:

```
clang++ -v Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0 Thread model: posix


brew info llvm llvm: stable 3.2 (bottled), HEAD http://llvm.org/ /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.2 (628 files, 106M) * https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/llvm.rb
==> Options
--all-targets   Build all target backends
--universal     Build a universal binary
--rtti  Build with C++ RTTI
--shared    Build LLVM as a shared library
--with-clang    Build Clang C/ObjC/C++ frontend
==> Caveats Extra tools and bindings are installed in /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.2/share/llvm and /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.2/share/clang.
```

Comment: Seem that changen the compile command to this is a fix : clang++ -g toy.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs` -O3 -o toy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that changing the compile command to this is a fix:

```
clang++ -g toy.cpp llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs -O3 -o toy
```