# Source builds with no errors/warnings but .so error "undefined symbol"

Tags: makefile, llvm

I am trying to use llvm for my project. I'm using some headers from llvm and have included their path in the Makefile. I am also using certain llvm libraries (.a), the paths and names of which I have included in the makefile. When I run the makefile, it build the source code without any warnings or errors but when I use the generated .so to run a plugin (for my project), I get the error for undefined symbol:

undefined symbol: _ZTIN4llvm2cl18GenericOptionValueE

where "_ZTIN4llvm2cl18GenericOptionValueE" is "llvm::cl::GenericOptionValue"

I build llvm following the commands on https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html

This error occurs irrespective of whether I link the the llvm libraries or not.
I followed the documents on llvm.org but haven't got any success. Specifically - http://releases.llvm.org/2.6/docs/Projects.html and http://releases.llvm.org/2.6/docs/MakefileGuide.html#overvars
The document about LLVM Makefile guide mentions Makefile.config and this is not present. Does nayone have any suggestions ?

The makefile is:

```
CXXFLAGS=-I$(PVLIB_HOME)/include -I$(PVLIB_HOME)/include/fmruntime -I$(PVLIB_HOME)/include/fmruntime/eslapi \
         -I/work/Project1/trunk/work/fastsim/Plugins/include -I/work/llvm/llvm-3.8.0/include -I/work/llvm/build/include/ --std=c++11 -I. -fPIC -c

PLUGIN_SRCDIR=Plugin
PIPELINE_MODEL_SRCDIR=Microarchitecture
BUILD_DIR=build
PLUGIN_UTILS=Utils

LIB_PATH=-L/work/llvm/build/lib 
LIBS=-lLLVMSupport -lLLVMAArch64Desc -lLLVMAArch64Disassembler -lLLVMMCDisassembler -lLLVMAArch64Info -lLLVMAArch64AsmPrinter -lLLVMMC -lLLVMAArch64Utils -ldl


OBJECTS = $(BUILD_DIR)/CAInterface.o $(BUILD_DIR)/InOrderPipelineModelFactoryPlugin.o $(BUILD_DIR)/InOrderPipelineModelPluginHandler.o \
      $(BUILD_DIR)/InOrderPipelineModelPlugin.o $(BUILD_DIR)/InOrder4StagePipeline.o \
      $(BUILD_DIR)/AArch64Decoder.o $(BUILD_DIR)/EventHandler.o $(BUILD_DIR)/Decode.o $(BUILD_DIR)/ExecuteALU.o \
      $(BUILD_DIR)/ExecutionUnit.o $(BUILD_DIR)/Fetch.o $(BUILD_DIR)/Scoreboard.o \
      $(BUILD_DIR)/Scoreboard.o $(BUILD_DIR)/Write.o   

#
# Build the final plugin
#
$(BUILD_DIR)/InOrderPipelineModel.so: $(OBJECTS)
$(CXX) -shared -o $@ $^ $(LIB_PATH) $(LIBS)

#
# Build the plugin 
#
$(BUILD_DIR)/InOrderPipelineModelFactoryPlugin.o : $(PLUGIN_SRCDIR)/InOrderPipelineModelFactoryPlugin.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 

$(BUILD_DIR)/InOrderPipelineModelPlugin.o : $(PLUGIN_SRCDIR)/InOrderPipelineModelPlugin.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 

$(BUILD_DIR)/InOrderPipelineModelPluginHandler.o : $(PLUGIN_SRCDIR)/InOrderPipelineModelPluginHandler.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 

$(BUILD_DIR)/CAInterface.o : $(PLUGIN_SRCDIR)/CAInterface.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 

#
# Build the model
#
$(BUILD_DIR)/InOrder4StagePipeline.o : $(PIPELINE_MODEL_SRCDIR)/InOrder4StagePipeline.cpp 
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 

$(BUILD_DIR)/AArch64Decoder.o : $(PIPELINE_MODEL_SRCDIR)/Utils/AArch64Decoder.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 

$(BUILD_DIR)/EventHandler.o : $(PIPELINE_MODEL_SRCDIR)/EventHandler.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 

$(BUILD_DIR)/Decode.o : $(PIPELINE_MODEL_SRCDIR)/Components/Decode.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 

$(BUILD_DIR)/ExecuteALU.o : $(PIPELINE_MODEL_SRCDIR)/Components/ExecuteALU.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 

$(BUILD_DIR)/ExecutionUnit.o : $(PIPELINE_MODEL_SRCDIR)/Components/ExecutionUnit.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 

$(BUILD_DIR)/Fetch.o : $(PIPELINE_MODEL_SRCDIR)/Components/Fetch.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 

$(BUILD_DIR)/Scoreboard.o : $(PIPELINE_MODEL_SRCDIR)/Components/Scoreboard.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 

$(BUILD_DIR)/Write.o : $(PIPELINE_MODEL_SRCDIR)/Components/Write.cpp
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ 


.PHONY: clean

clean:
  @rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o $(BUILD_DIR)/*.so
```

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140570/llvm-os-x-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-compile-error)?

Comment: Not sure if it matters here but note that the docs you're looking at are very old (2.6 was released in 2009). Your makefile says you're using 3.8.

Comment: @StanislavPankevich Just saw it.. I am not sure how to use llvm-config. I tried to follow the documents on the llvm.org website but still have doubts.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi Those are the only official documents available

Answer (score 0):

People say [1] this has to do with flag `-fno-rtti` missing among flags passed to compiler (CXX_FLAGS).

In the linked question [2] the author uses `llvm-config --cxxflags` to get the right CXX flags recommended by LLVM. On my machine the list of these flags does contain `-fno-rtti` and I believe it is what LLVM expects a compiler to be given by default.

[1] [[cmake] klee does not build without -fno-rtti #508](https://github.com/klee/klee/issues/508)

[2] [LLVM OS X symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 compile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140570/llvm-os-x-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-compile-error)

Comment: Tried adding  '-fno-rtt' but no luck

Comment: Which operating system and which version of LLVM are you using? Mine are Mac and LLVMs 3.9, 4.0 and 5.0. They all have `bin/llvm-config` in the same folder where `clang` and `clang++` are. Or you are using default Mac's compiler?

Comment: Linux with Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit). I have llvm-config in //vm/build/bin/llvm-config. same folder as clang and clang++

Comment: So the point is: did you try to copy all or all meaningful flags from `llvm-config --cxxflags` ? I would also look at other flags as well. `llvm-config --help` has quite a few options.

Comment: Ah.. I understood.. I tried that Stan, but can't get rid of the undefined symbol. I looked at other possible missing flags as well

Comment: Your version of LLVM?

Comment: I'm using llvm 3.8.0

Comment: Just to make sure the libs is not a problem could you try: `llvm-config --libs` and link them **all** and see what happens then?

Comment: I've done that before. Included all the possible libraries. It still throws the error. I think my linking is a problem. As in, whether I link the libs or not, it throws the error.